# Can't get checkboxes to clear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Checkboxes aren't clearing on my chrome extension...

Here is the javascript/HTML I have:

```js
$('#clearAll').click(function() {
  $(':checkbox').each(function() {
    $(this).removeAttr('checked');
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>

  <a href="index.html">Back</a>
  </br>
  <title>Segmenting to Partners</title>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      max-width: 300px;
      min-width: 300px;
      margin: 40px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h2 style="color:red"><u>blah</u></h2>
  <a id="clearAll" href="#">Clear All</a>
  <p class="c1"><span class="c9 c2">Workflow</span>
  </p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Solved Issue" value="Solved initial issue">Solve initial issue</br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="" value="">blah blah blah blah</br>

  <input type="checkbox" name="Solved Issue" value="Solved initial issue"><span class="c2">options 3</span>
  </br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Solved Issue" value="Solved initial issue"><span class="c2">option 4</span>
  </li>
</body>

</html>
```

The thing is it looks like this is functioning properly when you run it here, but it's not in my chrome extension i'm working on, and i just can't figure out why...

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Chrome extensions, but first of all, don't errors in it show up in the console of the developer tools? And secondly, if you use jQuery in an extension, don't you need to load it too? I see a script tag, but it's outside your html tag, and I think it's added by the Stack Overflow snippet editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a couple of issues going on with that code:

1. **Your jQuery version does not support the `prop` method.**

`prop` was not added to jQuery until v1.6.  For the version that you're using, you would use the `attr` method instead.

2. **You have put way too much logic in for what you are trying to do.   :)**

The logic that you need is to retrieve all of the checkboxes and change their `checked` value.  What you have retrieves all of the check boxs, loops through each one, changes the `checked` value, retrives all of the checkboxes again, and changes their `checked` value again.

You are heading the right way, but it looks like your code grew as you were trying to troubleshoot.   :)   This should take care of what you are trying to do:

```
$("#clearAll").click(function() {
    $(":checkbox").attr("checked", false);
});
```

---

**EDIT:** I just saw the other comment about supressing the default behavior of the `a` element.  My preferred way of doing this is by setting the `href` attribute to `javascript: void(0);`, like this:

```
  <a id="clearAll" href="javascript: void(0);">Clear All</a>
```

That supresses the default click action of the link in a cross-browser (including old versions of IE) way.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried this and it still doesn't work. I'm wondering if there is something else i need to do because all of this is happening within a chrome extension? thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1):

You're using jQuery v 1.2.3, which doesn't support the [**`prop`**](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method.

Upgrade to at least 1.6.

You could then simply do:

```
$('#clearAll').click(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
});
```

Also, it's best to use anchors (`a`) for their intended purpose – to take you somewhere.  A button may be more appropriate for clearing the checkboxes:

```
<button id="clearAll">Clear All</button>
```

**Snippet**

```js
$('#clearAll').click(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>

  <a href="index.html">Back</a>
  </br>
  <title>Segmenting to Partners</title>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      max-width: 300px;
      min-width: 300px;
      margin: 40px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h2 style="color:red"><u>blah</u></h2>
  <button id="clearAll">Clear All</button>
  <p class="c1"><span class="c9 c2">Workflow</span>
  </p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Solved Issue" value="Solved initial issue">Solve initial issue</br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="" value="">blah blah blah blah</br>

  <input type="checkbox" name="Solved Issue" value="Solved initial issue"><span class="c2">options 3</span>
  </br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Solved Issue" value="Solved initial issue"><span class="c2">option 4</span>
  </li>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Don't forget the `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the default anchor behaviour.

Comment: Ha, didn't even notice `clearAll` was on an anchor.  I'll update.